# How to start progress when saving video with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: objective-c, avassetexportsession

I can start progress bar when `AVAssetExportSession` is started.
Tell me how to start progress when it will be start.
I want to set progress bar with `AVAssetExportSession`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090760/progress-bar-for-avassetexportsession

Comment: Can you better describe your question? You say that you can start the progress bar, but you're asking how to start the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the method in which you call AVAssetExportSession you've got to set up a timer to update your UIProgressView once you've initiated the export:

`//AVAssetExportSession code here
    self.exportProgressBarTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateExportDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
...`

Then you need a method to update your display taking into account that the progress property on AVAssetExportSession goes from 0 - 1:

```
- (void)updateExportDisplay {
    self.exportProgressBar.progress = exportSession.progress;
    if (self.exportProgressBar.progress > .99) {
        [self.exportProgressBarTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Let me know it works for you or not!!

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Copy answered form this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090760/progress-bar-for-avassetexportsession

Comment: i cannot use progressbar. i'm using svprogressview HUD... how can i set progress with exportsession. tell me